# exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version and expected ';' at end of declaration list

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef VARIABLEEXCEPTION_H
#define VARIABLEEXCEPTION_H

#include <exception>
#include <string>

class VariableException : public std::exception {
private:
    std::string message;

public:
    VariableException(const std::string& errorMessage) : message(errorMessage) {}

    const char* what() const noexcept override {
        return message.c_str();
    }
};

#endif
```

I'm trying to create this exception and keep getting the following error.

```
../VariableException.h:14:29: error: expected ';' at end of declaration list
    const char* what() const noexcept override {
                            ^
                            ;
../VariableException.h:7:7: error: exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version
class VariableException : public std::exception { 

../VariableException.h:14:17: error: exception specification of overriding function is more lax than base version
    const char* what() const noexcept override {
```

Comment: My guess would be that your compiler or compiler configuration doesn't support `noexcept`. Please show a [mre] including compiler, compiler version and compiler command line

Comment: I'd have expected a *WTF is `noexcept`?* error message, but otherwise I'm pretty sure Alan's nailed it.  clang spits out almost exactly the given error if your version is old enough. Eg: https://godbolt.org/z/s4Mcd57K5

Comment: g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"project2.d" -MT"project2.o" -o "project2.o" "../project2.cpp"
In file included from ../project2.cpp:15: is this what u are looking for?

Comment: @DevenColeman you should set the compiler C++ Standard eg `-std=c++17` for C++17.  I don't see that in the above and depending on your version of g++ it could be defaulting to a very old version.

Comment: Please [edit] the required details into your question rather than adding them to the comments. We also need to know which compiler and which version of that compiler

Comment: @user4581301 recent versions produce the same error when run in c++98 mode https://godbolt.org/z/67rfxs71e, my next guess would be they're using apple clang which defaults to c++98